# Return a single element instead of an array from a WebAPI action method

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Here is my code in asp.net web-api controller.

```
   [Route("~/GetLoginEmployeeInfo")]
    public DataTable GetLoginEmployeeInfo()
    {
        DataTable dtUserInfo = new DataTable();
        Hashtable htMenuList = new Hashtable();
        htMenuList.Add("LoginKey", 20160636);
        htMenuList.Add("Passkey", 123);          
        dtUserInfo = DataTableByCommandFromStoredProc("GetUserByIDAndPass", htMenuList);          
        return dtUserInfo;  }
```

In WebApiConfig i have add:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I have got the result for json as: `[{"EmpID":"20160636","FullName":"Md Delower Hossain"}]`

But I want that as the following:`{"EmpID":"20160636","FullName":"Md Delower Hossain"}`

The parenthesis [] should be omitted for my programming purpose. What can I do?

Comment: does linq first or default work?   return dtUserInfo.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @BryanDellinger ty, thats work

Answer (score 1):

Your code *is* returning "standard JSON format", it's just an array.

This is because a DataTable contains, as its name already gives away, a table of data. Even if the table contains one row, its data is going to be returned as an array, in this case an array of one element long.

If you always just want to return the first row, then do that:

```
public DataRow GetLoginEmployeeInfo()
{
    // ...
    return dataTable.Rows[0];
}
```

Consider creating a model class that holds these properties instead of a DataTable.

Comment: Unfortunately `DataRow` is not serializable, so this will likely fail. Using a custom class would work though, as you also wrote.

Comment: Is it not possible that without returning an array from data table it will returns an object? Because the data table has many rows.

Comment: @Md.DelowerHossain _"the data table has many rows"_ - then why do you not want to return an array?